# Using process.stdin as IncomingMessage socket

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make a very simple wrapper around nodejs server handlers like `(req:IncomingMessage, res:ServerResponse) =>...` to use them in a cgi script context.

In a cgi script, the body of the request is given by stdin.  I thought this would work:

```js
#!/bin/node
// DOESN'T WORK
const {IncomingMessage} = require('http')

const req = new IncomingMessage(process.stdin)

var body = ""
req.on("data", function(chunk) { body+=chunk})
req.on("close", function() { console.log(body)})
```

But nothing is echoed from stdin.  However, attaching the event handlers to `req.socket` instead of just `req` does work:

```js
#!/bin/node
// DOES WORK
const {IncomingMessage} = require('http')

const req = new IncomingMessage(process.stdin)

var body = ""
req.socket.on("data", function(chunk) { body+=chunk})
req.socket.on("close", function() { console.log(body)})
```

What am I doing wrong? according to the docs `IncomingMessage` takes a socket as its parameter and stdin is a socket. How do I get the event handlers on the parent `req` object to read from stdin, as would be the case for an `IncomingMessage` object created by a `http.server`? I want this cgi dispatcher to be compatible with handlers that expect to be able to call `req.on('data'...)`.

Comment: *"...according to the docs `IncomingMessage` takes a socket as its parameter..."* Where in the documentation does it say that? I don't see it [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage). Yes, the constructor implementation accepts a parameter it calls `socket`, but that's not the same as documented behavior.

Comment: An assumed link, but [StdIn is a net socket](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processstdin). [`IncomingMessage`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_incoming.js) calls methods on `this.socket` which suggest it treats it as a net socket. There's also [this test](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/test/parallel/test-http-client-abort-response-event.js) which seems to suggest it accepts `net.socket`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the parameter is called "socket" and type inference in vscode suggests the signature is `new IncomingMessage(socket: Socket): IncomingMessage` so I assumed it takes a Socket. My mistake. Is there something I can do to approximate the behaviour I'm looking for?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know, sorry. :-) Seems odd that it's not working with what you have, documented or not. Good luck!

Comment: @Sean - Right, but again, not the same as *documented* behavior.

Comment: @JamesP have you tried to ask the same question on the [node.js github help repo](https://github.com/nodejs/help)? There you can ask the devs directly, perhaps they have solution and can answer your question.

Comment: Thanks @Marc, I didn't know that existed! I'll post something over there too